# regular expression to find at the end of lines

Tags: regex, search, find, notepad++

I have many lines that start like:

```
text.1
text.2
othertext.21
anothertext.50
dfgtext.161
```

what I need is to find the lines that has only .1 (not .21, not 11), only anytext.1

I use notepad++

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Notepad++ supports `$`, the end of line match, `\.1$` should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to match the end of the line, so try with `\.1$`

Answer (score 2):

If it's any text + .1 then try the follwing regex

```
.+?\.1$
```